# Pandas Datetime sort automatically removing timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, timestamp

[image]In my pandas df , I am converting the object columne to datetime with below command and sorting the df with the timestamp column as shown below.
However after doing all these steps 'timestamp part' is getting removed from the column and only date part is left.

```py
df0['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['Timestamp'] , format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df0.sort_values(by='Timestamp',inplace=True)
df0.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Expected output of timestamp column after sorting - 2019-06-02 14:45:00

Getting the output after sorting is - 2019-06-02

Comment: Can you add some sample data, 3-5 rows with your problem, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: added the sample data , I want sort using the first datatime column.

Comment: So if filter only first 10 rows like `df0 = df0.head(10).copy()` and then apply your solution, same problem?

Comment: with 10 rows the problem is not there , so how to solve the issue for the whole data.

Comment: I think solution working nice, maybe not displayed times only, because `00:00:00`.

Comment: Not really , I check there is no time part in the whole dataset after sorting.

Comment: ok, how is checked?

Comment: because it seems some data related problem, so without all your data not possible find problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I think It's only related with how the notebook shows the output, not the actual data saved in the dataframe.

Try outputting a larger sample that would include a time larger than 00:00:00.

For example, in my case I had time-series data with 15-min intervals. When I printed with

```
df.head()
```

output would be:

2020-01-01

2020-01-01

2020-01-01

...

but when I print with

```
df.head(50)
```

it actually shows

2020-01-01 00:00:00

2020-01-01 00:00:00

2020-01-01 00:00:00

..

2020-01-01 00:15:00

2020-01-01 00:15:00

..

Don't know why but, If you only print values with times 00:00:00 the output is suppressed to look like %Y-%m-%d without the time info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).